How to get the index value from the dropdown of v-combobox when down and up arrow buttons are clicked in vuetify 3
I have created a v-combobox where I am getting the values from other component in the same vuetify 3 project.
I want to get the index values of the highlighted value when arrow buttons are used.
This is the vue 3 code that I have used for getting the result,
<v-combobox
      v-resize="onResize"
      menu-icon=""
      :menu="showMenu"
      id="cobobox"
      v-model="comboboxValue"
      :custom-filter="customSearch"
      variant="underlined"
      color="primary"
      append-icon=""
      :name="value.name"
      hide-spin-buttons
      :error-messages="errMsg"
      :ref="value.name"
      open-on-focus
      :items="valueItems"
      :clearable="comboboxValue != '' ? true : false"
      clear-icon="mdi-close"
      @input="inputSetAndEmit(comboboxValue)"
      :placeholder="value.placeholder"
      @change="setAndEmit(comboboxValue)"
      :maxlength="value.maxlength ? value.maxlength : ''"
      :counter="value.counter ? value.counter : null"
      :persistent-counter="true"
      @keydown="onKeyPress($event)"
      :type="value.type"
      :prefix="value.prefix ? value.prefix : ''"
      v-model:search-input="comboboxValue"
      @update:search-input="
        comboboxValue !== ''
          ? ocrHeaderState
            ? filterItems(false, 'OPEN_OCR_LIST', $event)
            : filterItems(false, 'NO_OCR', $event)
          : ''
      "
      :inputmode="value.type == 'number' ? 'numeric' : null"
      :class="{ pdf_content: isPDFFile, search_page_style: isSearchPage }"
      @click="onFocus()"
      @click:clear="supplierNameClear"
      :menu-props="{ maxHeight: '280px' }"
      @blur="comboboxBlur"
      autocomplete="off"
    >
      <!-- todo for v-combobox -->
      <!-- @keydown="arrowKeyEvent($event)" -->
      <!-- added the below v-if as only the header was being disaplyed when values not present in the address book was eneterd -->
      <template v-if="valueItems.length > 0" #prepend-item>
        <div class="header_supplier" v-text="getHeaderText"></div>
      </template>
      <template #item="{ item, props }">
        <v-list-item
          v-bind="props"
          class="custom-list-item"
          :class="{
            hovered: ItemHovered === item.value,
            selected: item === comboboxValue,
          }"
          @mouseenter="onItemHover(item.value)"
          @mouseleave="onItemHoverExit(item.value)"
          @click="selectItem(item.value)"
          :style="{
            background: item.value == comboboxValue ? 'rgb(86, 177, 197)' : '',
            color: item.value == comboboxValue ? '#1976d2 ' : '',
          }"
        >
          <!-- commented as there were more warnings with v-list-item which was causing application to freeze -->
          <!-- <v-list-item-content> -->
          <!-- To do: remove below code after test -->
          <!-- <v-list-item-title>{{ item.value }}</v-list-item-title> -->
          <!-- </v-list-item-content> -->
        </v-list-item>
      </template>
    </v-combobox>

I have written @keydown event as,
function onKeyPress(e: any) {
    if (e.key === "ArrowDown" || e.key === "ArrowUp") {
        arrowKeyEvent(e);
    }
}

function arrowKeyEvent(e: any) {
      let ocrResultList = combinedList();
      let temp;
      if (ocrHeaderState.value && ocrResultList) {
        // for removing duplicate values that are present and not displayed in dropdown
        ocrResultList = [...new Set(ocrResultList)];
        if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
          // working for downarrow button
          // if condition is true it is for empty field and vice versa
          temp =
            comboboxValue.value === null
              ? ocrResultList[(navigatedIndex.value + 1) % ocrResultList.length]
              : ocrResultList[navigatedIndex.value];
          navigatedIndex.value =
            (navigatedIndex.value + 1) % ocrResultList.length;
        }
        if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
          navigatedIndex.value =
            (navigatedIndex.value - 1 + ocrResultList.length) %
            ocrResultList.length;
          console.log(navigatedIndex.value);
        }
        onItemHover(temp);
      }
      else {
        navigatedIndex.value = 0;
      }
    }

From this code, I am having difficulty in fetching the correct index value of the highlighted value present in the dropdown.
Kindly, provide a solution for the problem.
I have tried hardcoding the solution by using an alternative data member for getting the index, but still I am not obtaining the desired result.
